# RPG, how to slide the world

Tags: javascript, translate

I'm trying to make a smal rpg like a zelda with canvas.
This is the lik of my work : [WhitePlay](http://whiteplay.fr/moi/)

How can i when my charactere move, to move the world fluidly ? Now it's moving but bloc by bloc, how can i have a fluid translation ?

I don't know how to dynamicaly (with a translation animation) translate the world.

Any idea ?

```
onkeydown= function(e){
    //alert(e.keyCode);
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 49: // 1
            afficherInfos();
            break;
        case 38: // HAUT
        case 90: // Z
            if(deplacementOk(1)){
                yCamera--;
                yPerso--;
                initialiserMap(1);
                ctx.drawImage(perso2, 0, 0, 17, 23, (Math.round(nbCaseLongueur/2))*32, (Math.round(nbCaseHauteur/2))*32-16, 32, 48);
                if(infoAffiche == true){
                    document.getElementById('boiteAInfoYPerso').innerHTML = "Position Y = "+yPerso+"<br/>";
                }
            }
            break;
        case 40: // BAS
        case 83: // S
            if(deplacementOk(2)){
                yCamera++;
                yPerso++;
                initialiserMap(2);
                ctx.drawImage(perso1, 0, 0, 17, 23, (Math.round(nbCaseLongueur/2))*32, (Math.round(nbCaseHauteur/2))*32-16, 32, 48);
                if(infoAffiche == true){
                    document.getElementById('boiteAInfoYPerso').innerHTML = "Position Y = "+yPerso+"<br/>";
                }
            }
            break;
        case 68: // D
        case 39: // DROITE
            if(deplacementOk(3)){
                xCamera++;
                xPerso++;
                initialiserMap(3);
                ctx.drawImage(perso4, 0, 0, 17, 23, (Math.round(nbCaseLongueur/2))*32, (Math.round(nbCaseHauteur/2))*32-16, 32, 48);
                if(infoAffiche == true){
                    document.getElementById('boiteAInfoXPerso').innerHTML = "Position X = "+xPerso+"<br/>";
                }
            }
            break;
        case 37: // GAUCHE
        case 81: // Q
            if(deplacementOk(4)){
                xCamera--;
                xPerso--;
                initialiserMap(4);
                ctx.drawImage(perso3, 0, 0, 17, 23, (Math.round(nbCaseLongueur/2))*32, (Math.round(nbCaseHauteur/2))*32-16, 32, 48);
                if(infoAffiche == true){
                    document.getElementById('boiteAInfoXPerso').innerHTML = "Position X = "+xPerso+"<br/>";
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

function translationMap(a,b){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(a,b);
    ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
    ctx.restore();
}

function initialiserMap(sens){
    for(var cpt=0;cpt<nbCaseHauteur;cpt++){
        for(var cpt2=0;cpt2<nbCaseLongueur;cpt2++){
            switch(map[yCamera+cpt][xCamera+cpt2]){
                case " ":
                    ctx.drawImage(herbe, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "#":
                    ctx.drawImage(wall1, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "1":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre1, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre2, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre3, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "4":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre4, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "5":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre5, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "6":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre6, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "7":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre7, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
                case "8":
                    ctx.drawImage(arbre8, 0, 0, 32, 32, cpt2*32, cpt*32, 32, 32);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I don't need you to read all of my code* I agree, not ***all*** of it, but some would be quite helpful, or else this question is in danger of being closed as "Too Broad."

Comment: Excuse me, I'm French and am may be poorly expressed, the source code is not secret. I struggle to know what part you would arrange to know. And sry but i don't know how to add code in my comment :/

Comment: I know, just part of Stack Overflow is providing code when asking for coding help. And don't add code in the comments, use the `Edit` button to add to your original question.

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.creativebloq.com/html5/build-tile-based-html5-game-31410992

Comment: I think more details are required to answer this, and not just code.

Comment: Please update the question with additional information that describes what it is you want to accomplish that is not already working.

Comment: Ok, sry, what i try is : When i move my character, I don't whant it to move, i want the scenery move. What i want is to translate it, because actualy, what I'm doing is just print again the world with an other position :/ (Can imagine few mini-blink, but i want something fluid, like any GameBoy game, like zelda, pokemon, etc ...) sry if I don't give you all of the informations I don't realy understand what you realy need :/ But thanks for your help !

Comment: Thanks mkaatman, but your exemple don't need to do a translation true ? :)

Comment: Why not use javascript and backgroundPosition?  Make the world a big sprite.

Comment: Can you develop please eyegropram, i don't understand whant you mean :/